# How to test order-conscious equality of hashes

Tags: ruby, hash, equality, ordereddictionary

Ruby 1.9.2 introduced order into hashes. How can I test two hashes for equality considering the order?

Given:

```
h1 = {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
h2 = {"a"=>1, "c"=>3, "b"=>2}
```

I want a comparison operator that returns `false` for `h1` and `h2`. Neither of the followings work:

```
h1 == h2 # => true
h1.eql? h2 # => true
```

Comment: It's not a dupe of that question. That question does not consider comparing the order of sorted hashes.

Comment: Ruby 1.9.2 didn't introduce sorted hashes, it introduced ordered hashes. The hash remembers the insertion order. `keys` returns an array in insertion order as does `values`. If you need to have a sorted hash either sort the entries before creating the hash, or sort the hash as you extract the values. You gain nothing by having a hash that is sorted except some cosmetic attractiveness. It will not allow faster accesses.

Comment: I edited the question because I think the OP meant ordered hashes, not sorted hashes, and that caused controversy in the interpretation of the question. Please reedit to something else (but not as before) if my interpretation is wrong.

Comment: Your edit is not wrong, but I don't understand the distinction between sorted and ordered.

Comment: Ordered means what you intended. Sorted means that the keys are ordered by (for example) alphabetically so the key `"a"` comes before `"b"`, etc.

Comment: Ah, okay. Yes, that does make sense now I think about it. Thanks for the explanation and edit, and apologies for the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the easiest is to compare the corresponding arrays.

```
h1.to_a == h2.to_a
```

Comment: Did you try that? Based on the OP's hash definitions: `h1.to_a == h2.to_a
=> false`.

Comment: @theTinMan Yes. I think that is the expected result. You may be misinterpreting the question.

Comment: This is IMO preferable to the accepted answer since it also checks for equivalence of values.

Comment: I extrapolated from the other answer and also used `h1.values == h2.values`.

Answer (score 4):

You could compare the output of their `keys` methods:

```
h1 = {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3} # => {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}
h2 = {three: 3, one: 1, two: 2} # => {:three=>3, :one=>1, :two=>2}
h1 == h2 # => true
h1.keys # => [:one, :two, :three]
h2.keys # => [:three, :one, :two]
h1.keys.sort == h2.keys.sort # => true
h1.keys == h2.keys # => false
```

But, comparing Hashes based on key insertion order is kind of strange. Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, you may want to reconsider your underlying data structure.

Comment: I *think* I'm doing the right thing. I'm using it like a sorted array, testing each element in order. I'm using a hash instead, so that I can store a key (ID) for each element as well. If I understand correctly, the introduction of sorted hashes is to allow treating hashes like arrays (but with keys instead of ordinals), and hence this kind of usage is possibly expected?

Comment: @Sparhawk IMO it's less about treating a hash like an array and more about iterating the keys in the same order they were inserted, for Enumerable methods like `each`.  It's a subtle difference.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's actually what I meant, but I phrased it less eloquently and more vaguely. :)

Comment: +1 for pointing out that relying on this behavior is a sign that the choice of underlying data structure may not be optimal. @Sparhawk In my opinion (which is probably biased by my Python background and by the fact that I once spent months trying to debug a problem that I suspected but could never prove was due to an improper reliance on hash-ordering), even though Ruby 1.9 guarantees hash ordering, if your code logic depends on this feature, you're on thin ice and are probably making your code unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: @KyleStrand It certainly is confusing, but I'm not sure how else to do it. I'm dealing with biological sequencing data, so I have tens of thousands of entries across a genome. I'm comparing features that overlap in the genome, from two data sources. Rather than having to scan the entire hash for overlapping genes on every iteration, I'm using incrementing my genomic position across the sorted hash to minimise the amount of genes I have to look at. I agree the code becomes confusing, but it's more about optimising for large data sets in this case.

Comment: @Sparhawk Okay, what are your keys, and what are your values?

Comment: @KyleStrand It's been a while since I worked on this, but IIRC the keys are the gene IDs, and the position in the genome is somewhere in the values (I think in additional hashes, along with other information).