# Ruby Compare 2 hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Is there a way to compare 2 hashes if the keys are not in the same order?  for instance

```
hash1 = { "it"=> 10,"was"=>11,"the"=>14,"best"=>1,"of"=>12,"times"=>2,
          "worst"=>1,"age"=>2,"wisdom"=>1,"foolishness"=>1,"epoch"=>2,
          "belief"=>1,"incredulity"=>1,"season"=>2,"light"=>1,"darkness"=>1,
          "spring"=>1,"hope"=>1,"winter"=>1,"despair"=>1,"we"=>4,"had"=>2,
          "everything"=>1,"before"=>2,"us"=>2,"nothing"=>1,"were"=>2,"all"=>2,
          "going"=>2,"direct"=>2,"to"=>1,"heaven"=>1,"other"=>1,
          "way"=>1,"in"=>2,"short"=>1,"period"=>2,"so"=>1,"far"=>1,"like"=>1,
          "present"=>1,"that"=>1,"some"=>1,"its"=>2,"noisiest"=>1,
          "authorities"=>1,"insisted"=>1,"on"=>1,"being"=>1,
          "received"=>1,"for"=>2,"good"=>1,"or"=>1,"evil"=>1,"superlative"=>1,
          "degree"=>1,"comparison"=>1,"only"=>1 }


hash2 = {"superlative"=>1, "it"=>10, "going"=>2, "spring"=>1, "age"=>2, 
         "despair"=>1, "received"=>1, "good"=>1, "some"=>1, "worst"=>1, "was"=>11,
         "only"=>1,"us"=>2, "evil"=>1, "belief"=>1, "for"=>2, "darkness"=>1,
         "comparison"=>1, "short"=>1, "in"=>2, "present"=>1, "direct"=>2, "were"=>2,
         "way"=>1, "degree"=>1, "or"=>1, "of"=>12, "epoch"=>2, "incredulity"=>1,
         "period"=>2, "heaven"=>1, "other"=>1, "being"=>1, "its"=>2, "so"=>1,
         "authorities"=>1, "times"=>2, "we"=>4, "noisiest"=>1, "light"=>1, "hope"=>1,
         "foolishness"=>1, "everything"=>1, "far"=>1, "wisdom"=>1, "season"=>2, "like"=>1,
         "before"=>2, "had"=>2, "the"=>14, "nothing"=>1, "winter"=>1, "best"=>1,
         "that"=>1, "all"=>2, "insisted"=>1, "to"=>1, "on"=>1}
```

Each hash has the same keys. How would I go about comparing them and making sure that each key value is correct. All the questions and answers I've seen show hashes with the keys in the same order. Does it matter?

I've tried to use:

`hash1_1 = hash1.select{|k,_| hash2.has_key? k}`

which spit out:

```
{ "it"=>10, "was"=>11, "the"=>14, "best"=>1, "of"=>12, "times"=>2, 
     "worst"=>1, "age"=>2, "wisdom"=>1, "foolishness"=>1, "epoch"=>2, 
     "belief"=>1, "incredulity"=>1, "season"=>2, "light"=>1, 
     "darkness"=>1, "spring"=>1, "hope"=>1, "winter"=>1, "despair"=>1, 
     "we"=>4, "had"=>2, "everything"=>1, "before"=>2, "us"=>2, "nothing"=>1, 
     "were"=>2, "all"=>2, "going"=>2, "direct"=>2, "to"=>1, "heaven"=>1, 
     "other"=>1, "way"=>1, "in"=>2, "short"=>1, "period"=>2, "so"=>1, "far"=>1, 
     "like"=>1, "present"=>1, "that"=>1, "some"=>1, "its"=>2, "noisiest"=>1, 
     "authorities"=>1, "insisted"=>1, "on"=>1, "being"=>1, "received"=>1, 
     "for"=>2, "good"=>1, "or"=>1, "evil"=>1, "superlative"=>1, "degree"=>1, 
     "comparison"=>1, "only"=>1}
```

Please help me in explaining what I need to do.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two hashes with the same key/value pairs will be equal regardless of key order:

```
a = {:x => 1, :y => 2}
b = {:y => 2, :x => 1}

a == b
# => true
```

Comment: Even thought this behaviour is documented, isn't it weird that two hashes with different key order should be considered equal? It may be a compatibility "feature", but conceptually looks very dubious.

Comment: Hashes did not preserve insertion order until recently, so the comparison holds true for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @tokland, a hash table by definition is an unordered associative array, so the order should make no difference when comparing equality.

Comment: @infused: That was true in the past, but since Ruby 1.9.3 hashes are ordered.

Comment: Yes, all internal operations on Hashes preserve the creation order. That does not mean the order has any relevance to equality.

Comment: @infused: I see your point, but don't tell me there isn't something slightly wrong here: `a == b #=> true` but `a.keys == b.keys #=> false` :) I think as tadman said that the reason is backward compatibility.

Comment: I think @tokland makes a good point. Suppose we have an app where we are making use of key order (I've found uses for that myself) and want to know if two hashes `h1` and `h2`. have the same key order as well as being equal. Then I guess we'd have to do something like `h1.to_a == h2.to_a`. I'd not thought about that before.

Comment: How to test order-conscious hashes for equality in Ruby (≥ 1.9.2)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239544/how-to-test-order-conscious-hashes-for-equality-in-ruby-%E2%89%A5-1-9-2

Answer (score 3):

You are misinterpreting your results. Your code, works fine. Your algorithm is wrong though.

I'll take your hash1 and hash2 and create a difference using reject to get rid of everything that matches between them:

```
hash1["it"] = 9
hash1["Tony"] = "great"
hash2["Jeff"] = "awesome"
hash1.delete "was"

diff_in_hash1 = hash1.reject{|k,v| hash2[k] == v}
# => {"it"=>9, "Tony"=>"great"}

diff_in_hash2 = hash2.reject{|k,v| hash1[k] == v}
# => {"it"=>10, "was"=>11, "Jeff"=>"awesome"}
```

What you do with them now, is up to you. If you get empty hashes as a result, everything is the same.

There is also a [gem called 'hashdiff'](https://github.com/liufengyun/hashdiff) that could be of use.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me.  This will help in my code a lot. thank you.

Comment: Found a problem with this solution.  If I take a key,value pair off hash2, then the result still returns empty.

Comment: Tony, you have to use both diff_in_hash1 and diff_in_hash2 together. If you delete something off hash1 it will show up in diff_in_hash2 and vice versea.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand correctly, your main goal was to answer, if there is any difference between two hashes. So, the result of comparison should be `true` in case of exact match (both keys and corresponding values of two hashes), or `false` if not. As mentioned [here](https://olivierlacan.com/posts/hash-comparison-in-ruby-2-3/), since Ruby 2.3. you could use:

```
{ a: 1 } <= { a: 1 } = true
{ a: 1 } <= { a: 2 } = false
{ a: 2 } <= { a: 1 } = false
{ a: 2 } <= { a: 2 } = true
{ a: 1 } >= { a: 1 } = true
{ a: 1 } >= { a: 2 } = false
{ a: 2 } >= { a: 1 } = false
{ a: 2 } >= { a: 2 } = true
{ a: 1 } <  { a: 1 } = false
{ a: 1 } <  { a: 2 } = false
{ a: 2 } <  { a: 1 } = false
{ a: 2 } <  { a: 2 } = false
{ a: 1 } >  { a: 1 } = false
{ a: 1 } >  { a: 2 } = false
{ a: 2 } >  { a: 1 } = false
{ a: 2 } >  { a: 2 } = false
{ a: 1 } == { a: 1 } = true
{ a: 1 } == { a: 2 } = false
```

and

```
{ a: 1, b: 2 } > { a: 1 } = true
{ a: 1, b: 2 } == { a: 1 } = false
{ a: 1, b: 2 } >= { a: 1 } = true
{ a: 1, b: 2 } > { a: 1, b: 5 } = false
```