# Testing method that needs to sort hash by value in RSpec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, rspec2, rspec3

I am trying to test my method that takes a hash and re-orders it. I currently have:

```
def sort_views 
    help = view_counter.sort_by { |route, length| length }.reverse.to_h
    p help         #just so I can see the output in the test
  end
```

Then for my test I have:

```
describe "#sort_views" do
    let(:result) do {
      "/help_page/1" => 3,
      "/about/2" => 1,
      "/contact" => 1,
      "/home" => 1,
      "/index" => 2,
    }     end
    it "then sorts them via the view count" do
      expect(subject.sort_views).to be(result)
    end
  end
```

My issue is that the test passes.... However, I purposely have the order wrong at the moment in the result. Yet the p help in the method CORRECTLY re-orders it, so the output is actually different. I have tried eq and eql but I believe they just test structure? I know be and equal won't work...

For context my p help outputs: `{"/help_page/1"=>3, "/index"=>2, "/about/2"=>1, "/home"=>1, "/contact"=>1}` when the test is run.

So is there a way for me to say test the order of the result hash in my test too without calling .sort_by { |route, length| length }.reverse.to_h on my result variable as well??

Comment: I did a quick comparison of three methods of sorting a hash's key-value pairs by decreasing magnitue of values. That hash,  `h`, contained 100,000 random key-value pairs The execution times did not including converting the array of sorted key-value pairs to a hash, as that would be the same for all three methods. The methods and associated execution times in seconds were as follows: `h.sort_by(&:last).reverse` (0.063), `h.sort_by { |_,length| -length }` (0.040) and `h.sort { |(_,length1),(_,length2)| length2<=>length1 }` (0.163).

Comment: Hi Cary! Thanks for this added detail. Naturally going to be important for me if (when) I get my first role in commercial business. I didn't know too much about the &: which is procs I'm assuming?? So will look more into this right now. Thanks again / correct me if I'm wrong. Newbie learning here!

Comment: Ah never mind! Just found the sort_by(&:last) method. Thanks!

Comment: Right, it's shorthand for `sort_by { |a| a.last }`, `a` being a key/value pair `[k,v]`, so `a.last #=> v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the hashes are the same, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239544/how-to-test-order-conscious-equality-of-hashes). Hashes don't really have a concept of order, when you call the `sort_by` method it is converting the data to an array, ordering the array, and then returning an array. If you are converting the array to a hash you will lose the order essentially.

If you care about the order here, remove the `to_h` and just deal with the data as an array instead. Then your tests should work.

You can use `.to_a` in the test, and you don't need reverse in the sort.

```
view_counter.sort_by { |route, length| -length }

let(:result) do
  {
    "/help_page/1" => 3,
    "/about/2" => 1,
    "/contact" => 1,
    "/home" => 1,
    "/index" => 2,
  }.to_a
end
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Yep worked perfectly for test! You're amazing, so simple! But didn't overly know that about sort_by so that was key info as well. Have a good night!